# Django channels with callback inside synchronous code thread

Tags: python, python-asyncio, django-channels

This is an async function from Django channels, and I think I understand how to extend the asynchronous functionality within the consumer:

```py
async def status_msg_callback(self, status_dict):
    await self.channel_layer.group_send(
        self.group_name,
        {
            'type': 'status_msg',
            'message': {'type': 'status_dict_msg', 'status_dict' : status_dict}
        }
    )
```

I would like to pass this async code to some otherwise synchronous code that is running in another thread. I tried a few things which didn't work, and eventually I was able to make it work using the asgiref function `sync_to_async`. However, doing this also introduced a dependence on my channels project that otherwise wouldn't exist in the synchronous code.

I have now tried to use `asyncio.run()` when calling the channels callback and it appeared to work fine. However, I'm now questioning whether this is the correct way to do it and whether I'm overlooking something. I just realized I'm calling `asyncio.run()` inside a while loop, which seems wrong:

```py
while not stop_signal:
    while True:
        try:
            queue_msg = status_queue.get(timeout=1)
            status_dict = queue_msg
            asyncio.run(callback(status_dict))

            print('callback with queue_msg')
        except queue.Empty:
            queue_msg = None
            break

    time.sleep(1)
    if stop_signal:
        print('stop signal received')
```

The above code is using a queue to communicate with another process.

**Question** Is my use of `asyncio.run()` appropriate or is there another way to accomplish this? `callback` is the code from the first code block above.

Looking through the documentation (https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.get_event_loop) I found a few methods to create and manage the event loop manually, instead of using `run()`. Since I'm in a separate thread already, I would think that maybe the right way is to create a new loop at the start of the thread, use it, then close it at the end.

Comment: Why not call the method using the channel layer? https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/channel_layers.html#using-outside-of-consumers

Comment: I think the channels layer is what I was using in my first attempt mentioned above using `sync_to_async`. I've experimented with many things today for other parts of code I forgot what all I tried here. My current solution just references `asyncio` as I made one of my functions `async` and then I call the function I wanted with `await`.

Comment: It sounds wasteful to call `asyncio.run` every time - it is designed to be run once in the typical course of an application, so it's not efficient - it creates and shuts down a whole new event loop on every call. The alternative would be to create a new event loop (once), start `loop.run_forever` in a dedicated thread, and use [`asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe) to submit tasks to it. Surprisingly, my benchmarks show the same performance as with `asyncio.run()`, so I'm leaving this a comment.

Comment: Thanks. I've been reading about coroutines since this question, and what you're describing makes sense. I've also experimented with just making async/await functions, and it's working well, but does still have some undesirable blocking behavior. At this point I'm going for conventional, rather than fast, since I'd like the code to make sense and not be clever.